# How to sort object by number of orders that is obtained by `get_queryset` field

Tags: python, django

Here in code below I can get all the number of `orders` that are assigned to business.
But here is the question, how can I edit this code so that I can sort `users` by which business that has most `orders`?

```
class Order(models.Model):

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,  on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='ordersauthor')
    profile = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='orderscheck')
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='ordersarticle')
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
---------
class PublicUserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    queryset = User.objects.all().order_by('#HIGHEST NUMBER OF ORDERS')
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    filter_backends = [filters.SearchFilter,DjangoFilterBackend]
    pagination_class = StandardResultsSetPagination

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return (
            super()
            .get_queryset(*args, **kwargs)
            .annotate(
                num_orders=Count(
                    'orderscheck',
           orders__timestamp__range=Q(
                        orderscheck__timestamp__range=(date.today(), date.today() + timedelta(days=7))
                    ),
                )
            )
        )
----------
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    orders = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True, source='num_orders')
```

Initial Output:

```
{ User 1
            .....,
             "orders": 4,
        },
{ User 2
            .....,
             "orders": 2, 
        },
{ User 3
            .....,
             "orders": 3, 
        },
```

Expected Output:

```
{ User 1
            .....,
             "orders": 4,
        },
{ User 3
            .....,
             "orders": 3, 
        },
{ User 2
            .....,
             "orders": 2, 
        },
```

Comment: Share the `User` model.